# SQL Server : how to split a string using a comma as a separator

Tags: sql, t-sql, trim

I need to populate columns in my database for Latitude and Longitude, however the original information is stored as a single string

eg.

```
UDFChar1 = 41.243223,-8.183913
```

I am guessing that the TRIM command will come in useful here, but I do not know how I can tell it to stop exactly on the comma for each half.

What I'm hoping to be able to come up with is a simple UPDATE query as per the below:

```
UPDATE Asset
SET Lattitude = (SELECT LTRIM(UDFChar1)),
Longitude = (SELECT RTRIM(UDFChar1))
```

but obviously with some extra work in the LTRIM and RTRIM parts so that I am only selecting the data up to, and not including the comma in UDFChar1

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string *nod Kevchadders*

Comment: Welcome to SO. _Please_ try searching before posting, this question has been asked many times before.

Comment: Thank you, I did search extensively, but found nothing to match my exact criteria.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please try:

```
left(Col, charindex(',', Col)-1)
```

and

```
right(Col, len(Col)-charindex(',', Col))
```

sample

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(COL, CHARINDEX(',', Col)-1) Lattitude, 
    RIGHT(COL, LEN(COL)-CHARINDEX(',', Col)) Longitude
 FROM(
    SELECT '41.243223,-8.183913' Col
)x
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to adapt this to do exactly what I needed.

Comment: Code for reference -
'UPDATE Asset
SET Latitude = (SELECT left(UDFChar1, charindex(',', UDFChar1)-1)),
Longitude = (SELECT right(UDFChar1, len(UDFChar1)-charindex(',', UDFChar1)))'