# Two comma seperated cell merge with final output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Hey all I have the following SQL Query that I am using in order to get comma separated values from a cell:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT        
        uT.id AS UID, 
        uT.employeeID, 
        uP.type, 
        pP.name 
    FROM 
        usersTbl AS uT
    CROSS APPLY 
        dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(uT.userPerms,',') AS uPcommaItems
    INNER JOIN 
        usersPermissions uP ON uP.id = uPcommaItems.Item
    CROSS APPLY 
        dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(uT.userPermPages,',') AS pPcommaItems
    INNER JOIN 
        pagePermissions pP ON pP.id = pPcommaItems.Item
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    UID, 
    employeeID,
    STUFF(
            (
                SELECT 
                    ',' + stuff1.type
                FROM 
                    cte AS stuff1
                WHERE 
                    t.UID = stuff1.UID 
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''
          ) AS userPermissions,
    STUFF(
            (
                SELECT 
                    ',' + stuff2.type
                FROM 
                    cte AS stuff2
                WHERE 
                    t.UID = stuff2.UID
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''
          ) AS pagePermissions
FROM 
    cte AS t
```

The **userTbl** table looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
ID    | employeeID | userPerms | pagePermPAges
------------------------------------------------
15    | 3FdFieu9I  | 1,3       | 1,4,5,6
```

The **userPermissions** table looks like this:

```
----------------
ID | type
----------------
1  | Read
2  | Write
3  | Upload
4  | Admin
```

### And this is my **pagePermissions** table looks like:

```
ID | name
----------------
1  | bindex
2  | flight
3  | submit
4  | form
5  | information
6  | myPage
7  | register
```

My **current output** of the query above is this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID    | employeeID | userPermissions                         | pagePermissions
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15    | 3FdFieu9I  | Read,Read,Read...upload,upload,upload...| Read,Read,Read...upload,upload,upload...
```

It **should** read this though:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID    | employeeID | userPermissions | pagePermissions
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
15    | 3FdFieu9I  | Read,Upload     | bindex,form,information,myPage
```

Any MS SQL guru out there that can help me out?

Comment: Don't store comma separated strings in tables.  Use a proper junction table.  It is one thing to create a query that has the right output.  That is just for output purposes.  That is the wrong way to store the data.

Comment: As Gordon said...any many others on your last post for this same topic the problem is your data structure is wrong. If you are deadset on sticking with this denormalized nightmare you are going to have to use STUFF and FOR XML after splitting your strings to squash them back into the delimited list you want.

Comment: Looks an *awful lot* like your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696509/sql-server-stored-procedure-looping-through-a-comma-delimited-cell .....

Comment: @marc_s sure does. But with added table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this may help

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,A.employeeID
      ,usersPermissions = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' +[type] From userPermissions Where charindex(concat(',',ID,','),concat(',',A.[userPerms]    ,','))>0 For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
      ,pagePermissions = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' +[name] From pagePermissions Where charindex(concat(',',ID,','),concat(',',A.[userPermPages],','))>0 For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From usersTbl A
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Where did **pagePermPAges** come from John?

Comment: @StealthRT pagePermPAges was listed in your userTbl

Comment: @StealthRT Thought is looked odd, but I took it at face value.

Comment: Thanks for the help, John! :)

Comment: @StealthRT Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You need to get just the unique values for the permissions. You can get there via `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`. Here's your code modified using the former method:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT        
        uT.id AS UID, 
        uT.employeeID, 
        uP.type, 
        pP.name 
    FROM 
        usersTbl AS uT
    CROSS APPLY 
        dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(uT.userPerms,',') AS uPcommaItems
    INNER JOIN 
        usersPermissions uP ON uP.id = uPcommaItems.Item
    CROSS APPLY 
        dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(uT.userPermPages,',') AS pPcommaItems
    INNER JOIN 
        pagePermissions pP ON pP.id = pPcommaItems.Item
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    UID, 
    employeeID,
    STUFF(
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    ',' + stuff1.type
                FROM 
                    cte AS stuff1
                WHERE 
                    t.UID = stuff1.UID 
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''
          ) AS userPermissions,
    STUFF(
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    ',' + stuff2.type
                FROM 
                    cte AS stuff2
                WHERE 
                    t.UID = stuff2.UID
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''
          ) AS pagePermissions
FROM 
    cte AS t
```

Comment: Doing the **DISTINCT** helps but it just has the same values in both cells **Upload,Read**

Comment: You could not have expected otherwise, as both of your nested queries are 100% identical.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it
if you  Add

```
Group by
```

Before `For XML`